# How to insert a new column in the middle of a table

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro

Hi I am using Visual FoxPro Version 9.0, and I want to program a script that can make the following change to my current table.

At the moment I have this:

```
ID   NAME   AGE
```

And I want to end up with this:

```
ID   NAME   STUDYING   AGE
```

How can I add in that `'STUDYING'` column before the `'AGE'` column?

Thanks

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You mention in your tags "Visual-foxpro" and "sql", then comment that you are using "Access".

Can it be done, yes, but not necessarily easily outside the VFP-IDE.  However, if you DO have VFP, and want it specifically in that column, you would have to..

```
USE [path\YourTable.dbf] exclusive
modify structure
```

Then, insert click the button to add a new column, put in its name and then move it into the ordinal position you want.  VFP will do the rest for you, especially if you have auto-increment column for the ID.

If you are doing it through some means of an OleDb/ODBC connection from Access, then you would have to issue the SQL-Alter table command..

```
Alter table [YourTable] add [NewColumn] [DataType]
```

However, this will put the column to the end of the record structure.  In-itself, is not a big deal, as when you query data, you can have the columns returned in any order, regardless of their ordinal column position in the actual table.

Comment: I have a similar question, If i want to add a column with doubles and two decimal place, I used ALTER TABLE table2
ADD COLUMN base2 B(8[,2]); why do I have wrong syntax at add column?

Comment: @JingLi, by doing add column and specifying "B" for double, the size of 8 is implied.  You just need to specific decimal positions... Try add column base2 B(2).  You should be good.